# FEM applied to heat equation and incompatible conditions

Tags: finite-element, numerics, time-integration

Consider the problem $$u_t - \Delta u = f \text{ on } \Omega\times (0,T)\\u=0  \text{ on } \partial \Omega\times (0,T) \\ u(x,0)=g(x) \text{ on } \Omega$$
with $g$ NOT vanishing on the boundary. If I use a FEM discretization in space, what is the best a priori error (considering both space and time) that I can hope for? Under which time discretization? Is there anything else involving finite elements (e.g. space-time FEM) that would improve the situation?

Indeed, all the nice error estimates I came across with, assume compatibilty of initial and boundary condition...

Thank you in advance.

---

Cross posted also on Mathoverflow: [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421988/fem-based-solution-to-parabolic-problem)

Comment: You should mention that you asked almost the same question on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421988/fem-based-solution-to-parabolic-problem

Comment: Is the domain polygonal?

Comment: No, but of class $C^2$. I'd be interested in both cases though.

Comment: I found out DG methods in time to be some solution, maybe something simpler is available?